# Access an API from Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, api

I'm trying to use an API for the first time. Here is how I currently call it :

```
url = 'https://data.economie.gouv.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=prix-carburants-fichier-instantane-test-ods-copie&q=aire+sur+l%27adour&lang=fr&facet=id&facet=adresse&facet=ville&facet=prix_maj&facet=prix_nom&facet=com_arm_name&facet=epci_name&facet=dep_name&facet=reg_name&facet=services_service&facet=horaires_automate_24_24&refine.ville=Aire-sur-l%27Adour';
datas = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then((data: any) => {
    this.datas = data
  })
}
```

And HTML :

```
<pre class="text-white">
{{ datas | json }}
</pre>
```

The result shows a JSON like this :

[image: result]

Now, **how do I access it?** I already tried things like :

```
let data of datas :

data.records
data[0][records]
etc
```

Comment: Why do you need to access it? The call is async, so the data is available inside the subscribe

Comment: I don't understand sorry, I need to use datas from the API, how do I access it then ?

Comment: Inside the subscribe you can ‘use’ the data. If you want to loop through the data inside the template you can use *ngFor To loop through it (if you data is an array).

Comment: the best way to call an api is to create a service and then inject that service into component using dependency injection.. 
It is always recommended to use .subscribe method to use as httpClient return an observable so we need to subscribe that to use that further.. but here as you are converting into promise so that's also fine..please check the answer below for details.. thanks :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here, Please try to create a new method and use async/await.

Create a new method something like this -

```
public async getData()
  {
     await this.http.get(this.URL)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => this.datas = response['records'])
    .catch(err => { console.log ('error');
    });
  }
```

Now, You can call this method from your constructor something like this -

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 this.getData()
  }
```

Now, You should use *ngFor directive to iterate over the datas as it is an array so you can use this data to develop HTML.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of datas">
  {{data?.fields?.id}}
</div>
```

In this way, you can use this .
let me know if you need any further help on this .

please find the working link of stackblitz- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dukmlc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, it tells me that "Property 'records' does not exist on type 'Object'."

Answer (score 0):

Here an example, where json property rappresents your entire object:

```
 <span *ngFor="let element of json.records">
    {{element.datasetid }}
    {{element.geometry }}
    {{element.recordid }}
 </span>
```